# Prevent Dns.GetHostAddresses from throwing exceptions?

Tags: c#

So, Calling Dns.GetHostAddresses with a hostname for a dead website would often throw an exception stating "No such host is known".

Exceptions in my use case cause a lot of extra CPU usage where that extra CPU usage could be fatal.

Is there a way to override the method to just return null or something instead?

The exception is a SocketException indicating it uses sockets, I looked in the [Reference Source](https://referencesource.microsoft.com) and didn't find any Socket References in DNS.GetHostAddresses(string). I did see a SocketException object being created, but it wasn't used.

Comment: You're always welcome to write your own that behaves however you'd like.

Comment: @itsme86 I just need a way to convert a hostname to IP for connecting via TCPClient as it tends to work a lot more efficient when using an IP. How would I even "write my own".

Comment: The same way the .NET devs did. You could even start with the source code that you linked to and just tweak it.

Comment: @itsme86 Thats what I attempted, but it uses a lot of .net internals, ones that I cant access or even if I created into a new file of my apps namespace, would have a lot of permission errors.

Comment: How many Domains are you resolving that the overhead of catching an exception is "fatal"?

Comment: Well, you could always just start from scratch then. I'd start by grokking [the RFC](https://www.ietf.org/rfc/rfc1035.txt).

Comment: @DaveShaw Up to 2000 a minute.

Comment: Why not cache the ones that fail, then they only cause 1 exception (per day perhaps)?  How many of the 2000/min are dead?

Comment: 2000/min = 33/second.  If you were talking 2000 per second, you might have a point, but 2000/min is not a huge number, and proper use of threads/tasks should mitigate any use of exceptions.

Comment: @Neil Well it does seem to cause extra CPU usage then normal so idk what to tell u. Im already caching whats run, but it clears on close.

Comment: Why not 'pre-calculate' the IP addresses of these web-sites.  Instead of generating a list of host names, have a separate process (outside of the web server) that does the DNS lookup and generate a list of valid IP addresses.

Comment: @Neil Because its purposely fed urls, IMAP hostnames.

Comment: Btw, it clearly throws that `SocketException`, see line 266.

Comment: @pinkfloydx33 Oh right I see it now. Is there a way to just re-create the function? I literally just need it to return null instead of that socketexception

Comment: Copy paste the code, including the internals and anything they reference and then modify it to your needs?

Comment: @pinkfloydx33 Some of it mainly `IntPtr nativePointer = UnsafeNclNativeMethods.OSSOCK.gethostbyname(hostName);` was giving me issues copying its functions. Id basically have to copy like half of .net for it.

Comment: Hardly. Remove the Logging/Print statements, the Socket.LegacySupportsIPV6 test and you're left with the single DllImport that you cited and the  `hostent` structure. It's definitely doable and not that difficult either. If you **need** it to work this way (it's still not clear that you *really* do) then you'll find a way to make it work. Two of us have already told you how using the .NETsource code, two others have suggested caching alternatives, and Roger has suggest some direct p/invoke. None of it is automatic--you're going to have to put some effort into it.

Comment: And you really should look a tthe rest of your code. While Throw/catch is not really super cheap, even 2000 calls a second should not really make a problem.

Comment: @pinkfloydx33 I actually did manage to get it running, it "works" and NO exceptions, but now im getting a LOT of ArgumentExceptions with `NativeToHostEntry()`'s `TempList.Add(new IPAddress(IPAddressToAdd));`.

Comment: The issue I mentioned right above, if I have it happen, then re-try again on the exact same hostname, it will work. Seems like some kind of cache thing. - Heres the exception stack aswell as the int32 that was read using marshal: https://i.imgur.com/6qLPgzf.png

Comment: Strangely, if I set `IPAddressToAdd = Marshal.ReadInt32(nativePointer);` to `IPAddressToAdd = (UInt32)Marshal.ReadInt32(nativePointer);` and change IPAddressToAdd from int to Uint32, it works, it no longer provides < 0 int's (-xxxx). Is this a possible bug in .net framework's end that's gone unnoticed?

Answer (score 0):

Use P/Invoke to access the Win32 DNS API. Start here: https://www.pinvoke.net/default.aspx/dnsapi.DnsQuery

Answer (score 0):

Try using [Dns.BeginGetHostAddresses()](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.net.dns.begingethostaddresses?f1url=https%3A%2F%2Fmsdn.microsoft.com%2Fquery%2Fdev15.query%3FappId%3DDev15IDEF1%26l%3DEN-US%26k%3Dk(System.Net.Dns.BeginGetHostAddresses);k(TargetFrameworkMoniker-.NETFramework%26f%3D255%26MSPPError%3D-2147217396&view=netframework-4.7.2) `IAsyncResult` callback.
You can't avoid the exception if the Host entry is not resolvable (this is the way most `System.Net` methods work, like it or not), but is not raised in the UI thread.

I'm not absolutely sure whether this can solve the problem, but I didn't notice any CPU spikes while running it (just the first time it's used, but the method was called from a `Button` click event).

```
IPAddress ResolvedIpAddress = null;
GetHostIpAddressAsync("www.hfkhkhfhkf.com", this.ResolvedAddressCallback);


protected internal void ResolvedAddressCallback(IPAddress address)
{
    this.ResolvedIpAddress = address;
    //Eventually, if an UI update is needed
    this.BeginInvoke((MethodInvoker)delegate { 
        label1.Text = address != null 
                    ? ResolvedIpAddress.ToString() 
                    : "<Host not found>";
    });
}

internal static void GetHostIpAddressAsync(string sHostName, Action<IPAddress> BGHAActionCallback)
{
    IPAddress IpAddress = null;
    Dns.BeginGetHostAddresses(sHostName, new AsyncCallback((asyncResult) =>
    {
        try
        {
            IPAddress[] ipAddresses = Dns.EndGetHostAddresses(asyncResult);
            if (BGHAActionCallback != null)
            {
                if (ipAddresses.Length > 0)
                    IpAddress = ipAddresses[0];
                BGHAActionCallback?.Invoke(IpAddress);
            }
        }
        catch (Exception) { BGHAActionCallback?.Invoke(null); }
    }), null);
}
```

Answer (score -1):

I'm not sure if I understand your problem correctly, but are you trying to achieve something like this?

```
private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        try
        {
            IPHostEntry hostEntry;

            hostEntry = Dns.GetHostEntry(textBox3.Text);

            if (hostEntry.AddressList.Length > 0)
            {
                var ip = hostEntry.AddressList[0];
                Socket s = new Socket(AddressFamily.InterNetwork, SocketType.Stream, ProtocolType.IP);
                s.Connect(ip, 80);
                textBox5.Text = ip.ToString();
            }

        }
        catch
        {
             textBox5.Text = "No Conversion available";
        }
```

Comment: OP said exceptions are too expensive.

Comment: And isnt GetHostEntry deprecated?